# Why does malloc(1) work for storing 4 byte integers?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

From what I understand, malloc(x) returns a block of memory x bytes long.

So to store a 4 byte integer, I would do:

```
int *p = (int *)malloc(4);
*p = 100;
```

Because sizeof(int) returns 4 for me.

However, if I do:

```
int *p = (int *)malloc(1);
*p = 100;
```

It seems to work exactly the same, with no issues storing the value.

Why does the amount of memory requested with malloc() not seem to matter? Shouldn't a 4 byte integer require malloc(4)?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Repeat that 2nd code in a loop couple of 1000 times and your program will probably crash & burn as it ought to.

Comment: C has no bounds checking. Writing out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I also recommend you read [this discussion about casting the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @Lundin possibly not, if the allocator has a minimum allocation size

Comment: Behavior of your program is undefined. It works just because `malloc` usually returns pointers aligned to largest data type (usually 8 or 16 bytes), so in most implementations allocating a few bytes allocates at least 8 or 16 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

If this works in your case it just works by chance and is not guaranteed to work. It is undefined behavior (compare [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)) and everything can happen.

What did you expect to happen? Your program crash?

That might still happen if you call `malloc` and `free` a bit more often. `malloc` often takes some bytes more than requested and uses the extra space for Managing (linked list of all memory blocks, sizes of memory blocks). If you write some bytes before or after your allocated block then chances are high that you mess with the internal management structures and that subsequent `malloc` of `free` will crash.

If malloc internally always allocates a minimum of n bytes then your program might only crash if you access byte n+1. Also the operating system normally only be protects memory based on pages. If a page has a size of 512 bytes and your malloc-ed byte is in the middle of a page then your process might be able to read-write the rest of the page and will only crash when accessing the next memory page. But remember: even if this works it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` as all memory block allocation functions from C runtime or OS Kernel are optimized for memory access and object alignment.

Moreover, `malloc` specifically, allocate an hidden control block in front of the allocated space to keep track of the allocation (space required, **space allocated**, etc).

**`malloc` must also to guarantee that the allocated memory address is suitably aligned for any storage object**, this means that the block will start on an 8, 16, 32 or even 64 or 128 bytes boundary depending on the processor and generically from hardware (i.e. some special MMU). The boundary is also dependent on access speed, some processor have different behavior with different memory accesses (1, 2, 4, 8, ... bytes) and address boundaries. This constraints drive `malloc` code spec and allocator logical memory blocks partitions.

On practical side lets consider an allocator for X86 processor, it generally give back a block aligned on an 8 bytes boundary (32 bits code), that is useful for int, float and even doubles. To do this `malloc` divides the available memory arena in 'blocks' that are the minimal allocation space. When you allocate even 1 byte the function allocates at least one block. Eventually this block can host an integer, or even a double, **but it is implementation dependent, and you can't consider it deterministic**, because in future versions of the same function the behavior can change.

Now that, I hope, is clear because your code seems to work, keep well in mind that **this is Undefined-Behavior and you must keep it for that**. IT can work now, not with the next revision, it can crash on some hardware and not on another processor or machine.

Answer (score 3):

For this we should know how malloc function works internally. To allocate memory dynamically, each operating system make use of system calls. We can dynamically allocate memory using these system calls. These system calls are different from one OS to the other.

So the system calls of one OS might not work for the other OS. And moreover if we are using system calls to allocate memory dynamically then our program will be platform dependent. So to avoid this dependency we use malloc function. Now it is the responsibility of malloc function to make the appropriate system calls based on the OS to allocate memory dynamically.

So malloc itself invokes system calls and it will be a very slow process because each time we are asking for dynamic memory it has to make use of system calls. To avoid this whenever we request dynamic memory it usually allocate extra memory so that next time the system call can be avoided and the remaining chunk of previously allocated memory can be used. And that's why your program is working as malloc is allocating extra memory.

Comment: Even after setting #pragma pack(1), still shows 4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

> It seems to work exactly the same, with no issues storing the value.

You invoke undefined behavior with your code, so you cannot tell that it works. In order to allocate memory for an integer, you should do:

```
int *p;
p = malloc(sizeof (*p) ); //you can use sizeof(*p) as p is already declared and here you use the size of its content, which is actually the size of an int
if (p != NULL)
    *p = 100;
```

Comment: A better variant would be `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p)`

Comment: `sizeof *p`, not `sizeof(p)`, which is the size of the pointer.

Comment: A note on *why* you are allowed to refer to `*p` in the `sizeof` call wouldn't go amiss. This is a nice answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba what do you mean? I have not understood what you encourage me to clarify.

Comment: For a beginner, `sizeof (*p)` before the declaration of `p` has "finished" looks odd.

Answer (score 2):

The C programming language gives you the ability to shoot yourself in the foot.

It intentionally burdens the programmer with the charge that they ought to know what they are doing. Broadly speaking the reasons are to achieve performance, readability, and portability.

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*. If you ask for 1 byte then expect to get only one usable byte back. The fact that the operating system and C runtime library seems to be giving you back a little more than that is no more than a curious peculiarity.

On other occasions the compiler might simply eat your cat.

Finally, use `sizeof` in the call to `malloc` rather than hardcoding the size of an `int` type: on many systems `sizeof(int)` is 2, 4 is commonplace, and all values greater than 1 are allowed by the standard. In your case, using either `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(*p)` is possible. Some folk prefer the latter since then you're not hardcoding the type of the variable in the `sizeof` call, so guarding you against possible variable type changes. (Note that `sizeof(*p)` is compile-time evaluable and uses static type information; hence it can be used before `p` itself "exists", if you get my meaning.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply, when you are allocating 1 byte for the int, there are 3 bytes following it that are not actually allocated for it, but you can still use them. You are getting lucky that these aren't being changed by something else during your tests, and that it isn't overwriting anything important (or maybe it is). So essentially this will cause an error once those 3 bytes are needed by something else -- always malloc the right size.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `malloc` is implemented such a way that it allocates memory with the size not less than the size of the paragraph that is equal to 16 bytes. 
So when you require for example 4 bytes of memory `malloc` actually allocates 16 bytes. However this behavior does not described in the C Standard and you may not rely on it. As result it means that the program you showed has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of padding, and even though you are calling `malloc(1)` padding bytes are coming with the memory.
please  check this link http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_31.html